# Where can I find the source code from the book "The Art of Molecular Dynamics Simulation"?

Tags: reference-request

I need the source code (written in C programming language) for the following book:

[image]

The Page-`xiii` of the book says:

> **Software availability**
> Readers interested in downloading the software described in this book in a computer-readable form for
> personal, noncommercial use should visit the Cambridge University
> Press web site at http://uk.cambridge.org, where the home page for
> this book and the software can be found; a listing of the programs
> included in the software package appears in the Appendix. Additional
> material related to the book, as well as contact information, can be
> found at the author’s website – [http://www.ph.biu.ac.il/~rapaport](http://www.ph.biu.ac.il/%7Erapaport).

None of the supplied URLs work as intended. Both are invalid URLs.

[**This link**](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/art-of-molecular-dynamics-simulation/57D40C5ECE9B7EA17C0E77E7754F5874) seems to be the page for the book. However, I haven't found the source code.

Where can I find the source code from the book "The Art of Molecular Dynamics Simulation"?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://github.com/efrenaserra/moleculardynamics) Github repository as it claims it contains the source code of that book.

Comment: @Camps, The source code was supposed to be in C, not it Python. The GitHub repository contains python code.

Comment: This [repo](https://github.com/niktre/md_small) has code written in C. And the description says it is based on the book.

Comment: [Another one](https://github.com/StefSchenkelaars/molecular-dynamics) with limited description, but all C code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thankfully [WaybackMachine](https://archive.org/web/) archived a copy of the Art of Molecular Dynamics Website.

In this [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20010415185328/http://www.ph.biu.ac.il/%7Erapaport/mdbook/info.html), you can find the C source code associated with the book, with the following information stated along with it.

> The software that appears in the book is available for personal use;
> the software is available here in tar+gzip and zip formats (please
> contact the author if you have difficulty retrieving the software or
> questions regarding its use).